# How to cure Battery draining and lagging problem

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, lagging

**Question How to  cure Battery draining and lagging  problem**

I have lyf water 7 ls-5504 mobile it's been rooted through super user to use link2sd and link apps. But before rooting it's have huge proble of draining battery it's battery drains 25% within if screen off to 10-15min from 100% to 75% very fast. One day it got battery calibration problem to it showed 0% and still it was working... Then I went to sevice center and they formatted and installed th android 5.11 stock rom again they electrically tested  said battery is okay but software problem or may be software draining it.

As I  googled and founded that some softwares setting consumes battery and to find them and kill or.force.stop.them and to cha he settings... Which switch off did ie. Developer option> windows animation scale / transaction animation scale/ animator duration scale

[image: developer option drawing option]

This option and GPU rendering I turned off and Bluetooth WiFi off and background process limit to 2  in setting developer options  which reduced the battery draing in off screen but still while using its
draining to fast in compared to same company other model with same 3000mh battery.

So after rooting I installed  greenify and accu battery to solve the battery charging or draining  problem still it's same.

I tried to hybernate through greenify app  one or two apps which are silently memory resident    but I can't restrict system (google.play services) so I screenshot the developer option process stats  to refer you apps running in memory

[image: process stats screenshot]
[image: process stats screenshot 2]

From above photo I have given to give reference how much mh or percentage battery is consumed in charging and discharging . If any expert can find the reso. Or app of its draining battery fastly and second phone hangs lags and respond to late and stuck in browsing many times  and many time I have to close all running apps and restart them again. Is it due to rooting or.permissoon apps or link2sd apps or due to accubattery or greenify.  As link2sd accubattery or greenify is no where in process stats ... I had not linked or moved system apps or random used apps  to external sd card..

Now if u can help or advice.me how to redicate or troubleshoot or find the app which is draining the battery or hanging or lagging . The phone....any more reports or details required for your refrence I can send screenshot ...any opinion advice to solve help will  be welcomed

Following is screenshot of battery apps usage of android 5.1.1 native

[image: settings battery statistics screenshot]

Following is accubattery aps stats infor.of battery discharges and charging stats

[image: accubattery apps charging stats screenshot]
[image: accu batery apps battery usage stats screenshot 2]
[image: acuu battery apps discharging usage screenshot]

[image: accubattery discharge speed apps wise usage screenshot]

[image: accubattery discharge speed screenshot]
[image: accu battery apps charge status screenshot]

From above photo I have given to give reference how much mh or percentage battery is consumed in charging and discharging . If any expert can find the reso. Or app of its draining battery fastly and second phone hangs lags and respond to late and stuck in browsing many times  and many time I have to close all running apps and restart them again. Is it due to rooting or.permissoon apps or link2sd apps or due to accubattery or greenify.  As link2sd accubattery or greenify is no where in process stats ... I had not linked or moved system apps or random used apps  to external sd card..

Now if u can help or advice.me how to redicate or troubleshoot or find the app which is draining the battery or hanging or lagging . The phone....any more reports or details required for your refrence I can send screenshot ...any opinion advice to solve help will  be welcomed

Comment: How long does battery hold charge in stand-by until phone dies?

Comment: @alecxs bro it drains and if we surf or use it jut run 2-3 hours...and if idle stand by in off screen  it finish in 6-8 hours.....the other model battery  of lyf water 8 3000mh  same as lyf water 7 3000mh but the mobile dvice and batgery physical width. And height is different don't know will it fit yes it can be externally  fitted ...the draining of battery in lyf water 7 is from the day I purchased the mobile...it's battery  usage is high as its display Is larger and may be hardware parts use more  battery

Comment: How long does battery hold charge in fastboot mode? If not more than 6-8 hours too discard that battery/device